# Creating a java executable

Tags: java, command-line, executable

What is the command-line equivalent (Linux) of

```
gcc -o executable file.c
```

for a jar file? (Java instead of gcc)

I know it is possible to do because at my school, all that is necessary is writing "mars" (the MIPS simulator) in command-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute a Java JAR file, run the following command, replacing `YourJarFile.jar` with the filename of your JAR file.

```
java -jar YourJarFile.jar
```

**EDIT:** There is *no way* to execute a Java JAR like

```
./YourJarFile.jar
```

because the Java Runtime Environment must interpret the JAR file, not the operating system's `sh`.

Comment: I think the poster is asking about creating the jar, not executing it.

Comment: This is, by the way, the closest approximation you're going to get to an executable.  Java doesn't do executables.

Comment: I know, that is what I have been doing, but I want to be able to do it with one word. I my c example, I would be able to write ./executable to run my program.

Comment: @spatara: You can't.  There is no way to do it with `java` and `javac`.  I think `gcj` might generate executables, though.

Comment: You could, of course, create a shell script that runs the appropriate `java` command.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct, native, command-line equivalent.  @Deltik provides the closest compatible method.

Answer (score 0):

```
javac myfile.java
```

presuming you have a JDK installed ;)

Answer (score 0):

To compile Foo.java and Bar.java:

```
javac Foo.java Bar.java
```

To put the compiled class files in a jar:

```
jar cvf classes.jar Foo.class Bar.class
```

Note that if you put your classes in packages, which you should, your class files will be in a sub-directory and you will have to change the jar command accordingly.